# More elegant ways to resolve nuget dependencies for red squiggly in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I am learning generic host with Visual Studio 2017 and the sample I am working on is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/host/generic-host/samples/2.x/GenericHostSample/Program.cs). I retype the code row by row and I find red squiggly lines.

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
    {
        configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        configHost.AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true);
        configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "PREFIX_");
        configHost.AddCommandLine(args);
    })
```

Pressing `ctrl+.` sometimes does not work if we don't load the relevant nuget packages.

I try fixing one by one by looking up the `using` namespaces followed by loading the relevant nuget packages.  Unfortunately,  it is not always easy because of the extension methods that exist in different nuget packages with out-of-sync names.

## Question

Is  there any more elegant way to solve this issue?

## Edit

Should I make the following notes?

```
IHost host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(icb =>
    {
        //FileConfigurationExtensions class in
        //Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
        icb.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

        //JsonConfigurationExtensions class in
        //Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
        icb.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    })
```

> Education should not focus on remembering something that we can easily look up. It should focus on building problem solving skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any more elegant way to solve this issue?

Yes, when we use nuget to manage our references, nuget has records to hold which packages we have installed.

Return to the previous directory:

[GenericHostSample.csproj](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/host/generic-host/samples/2.x/GenericHostSample/GenericHostSample.csproj)

you will find the project file `GenericHostSample.csproj`, then open it, you will find following content:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

So, we could to know which nuget packages and their versions are needed for this project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK. It means there is *NO* elegant way. I will close this answer.

Comment: @TheInventorofGod, I may not understand the elegant way you said, you can copy above code and paste it to the project file .csproj, nuget will add those packages to your project automatically, so that you do not need add them manually.